# Google Cloud Application stops working when not being used for a while

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud and I have hosted my application using Google App Engine. I'm also using Google Cloud SQL. My problem is that after some time like maybe 6-7 hours or even less my application stops working as if it got shut-down.

I can access the URL but can see NO data... Cloud SQL still works because if I try to connect to the IP address, I can see my data in MySQL.

I need to always deploy it again from eclipse and it starts working again.

How can I fix this problem? My Cloud SQL settings are set to Always running as I'm still on a trial period. Technically it should never shut-down but I don't why it is.

Can someone help?

Comment: It may just be hibernating. GAE spins up instances on-demand, and if there's no demand then it hibernates the app. It usually takes about a minute for my apps to warm up again after hibernating. You can avoid this by keeping one instance warm all the time, but that costs $.

Comment: May be you can  try setting up warm up requests. [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Warmup_requests)

Comment: Can you provide a small App Engine app and the steps to reproduce this problem?

Comment: If you need to have an instance that is 'always on' consider using a manually scaled instance. Also, logs are your friend.